# Evaluate limit question without L'Hopitals (Homework help)

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x\to 1}$$\frac{\sin(1-\sqrt{x})}{x-1}$

Use of L'Hopitals rule is not allowed by the teacher. I tried to use formula of $\sin(a-b)=\sin a\cos b-\cos a\sin b$ but i couldn't go any further.

Comment: Is there a mistake? In the nominator sine is not a function of $x$.

Comment: So sorry it is x not 1

Comment: Even the standard limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{sin x}{x}$ cannot be used?

Comment: It is allowed to use it but not l'hopitals rule

Comment: Hint: factor the denominator as if it were a difference of squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find this limit, you're going to have to employ the following well-known fact from elementary limit theory:
$$
\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}=1
$$

What it says is that as $x$ approaches zero, sine of $x$ over $x$ approaches $1$. Here's [the proof](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Dy8ASSE8ok&index=8&list=PLF5E22224459D23D9#t=12m29s) of that (YouTube video). Also notice that as $x$ approaches $1$, the expression $1-\sqrt{x}$ approaches 0. Lastly, recall your conjugate multiplication facts from the high-school days and you're all set to take this limit.

$$
\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)}{x-1}=
\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \left(\frac{\sin\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)}{x-1}\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1-\sqrt{x}}\right)=\\
\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \left(\frac{\sin\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)}{1-\sqrt{x}}\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{x-1}\right)=
\lim \limits_{1-\sqrt{x} \to 0} \frac{\sin\left(1-\sqrt{x}\right)}{1-\sqrt{x}} \cdot \lim \limits_{x \to 1} \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{x-1}\cdot\frac{1+\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}\right)=\\
1 \cdot \lim \limits_{x \to 1} \frac{1-x}{(x-1)(1+\sqrt{x})}=
-\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \frac{x-1}{(x-1)(1+\sqrt{x})}=
-\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}}=\\
-\frac{1}{1+1}=-\frac{1}{2}
$$

This is just one of the several possible ways to find this limit. Siong Thye Goh, however, has offered you a more elegant way to do that (elegance in the fact that it's just a tad shorter).

Comment: Why did you write it as $\lim_{1-\sqrt{x}\to 0}$ doesn't it have to be $\lim_{x\to 1}$ too?

Comment: As $x$ approaches $1$, what number does the value of $1-\sqrt{x}$ approach? Well, $0$! In the limit $\lim \limits_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin{\theta}}{\theta}=1$ (I replaced $x$ with $\theta$ to make the point clearer), think of $\theta$ as something—some kind of expression, mathematical statement, anything at all—getting closer and closer to zero. And now think of the original $x$ as being behind $1-\sqrt{x}$ driving it to zero as it approaches $1$.

Comment: In other words, $x$ approaching $1$ entails the fact that $1-\sqrt{x}$ goes to zero. That's why you can switch them up it in your original limit. Does this make more sense to you now?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sin(1-\sqrt{x})}{(\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}+1)}$$

Answer (score 2):

A different solution without needing $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$: 
$$\frac{\sin(1-\sqrt{x})}{x-1} = \frac{\sin(1-\sqrt{x}) - \sin(1-\sqrt{1})}{x-1} = -\frac{\cos(1-\sqrt{\xi})}{2\sqrt{\xi}}$$ for a $\xi \in (1,x)$ by the mean value theorem.
And because $\xi \to 1$ if $x\to 1$ we get:

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sin(1-\sqrt{x})}{x-1}  = \lim_{\xi\to 1} -\frac{\cos(1-\sqrt{\xi})}{2\sqrt{\xi}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Noticing that $x-1=-(1-\sqrt{x})(1+\sqrt{x})$ then $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin(1-\sqrt{x})}{-(1-\sqrt{x})(1+\sqrt{x})}=\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin(1-\sqrt{x})}{1-\sqrt{x}}\cdot \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{-1}{1+\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{-1}{1+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{-1}{2},$$ using the fact that $$\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin(u)}{u}=1.$$

Comment: @Fawad You’re right! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $1-\sqrt x=y\implies x=(1-y)^2$

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sin(1-\sqrt{x})}{x-1}=\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\sin y}y\cdot\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac1{y-2}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to work around our *limit* :

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sin(1-\sqrt{x})}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sin(1-\sqrt{x})}{(\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}+1)}$$

since $x-1 = (\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}+1). $

A known standar limit tells us that :

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

so :

$$ \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sin(1-\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}-1} \cdot \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{x}+1)} = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: This was homework help,you should just have given hint,not answer,answer should be -1/2 btw

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$x-1={\left (\sqrt x \right )}^2 -1^2$

$x-1=(\sqrt x +1)(\sqrt x-1)$